# SetWindowPos() works for a dialog, but not in a CPropertyPage

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cpropertysheet

I have a dialog of type `CPropertyPage`, where within the dialog I'm showing a `CPropertySheet` object to display a couple of tabs.

Initially, when I was testing this dialog, I had it running as a separate dialog window (`dialog.DoModal()`). When I am running it as a separate dialog window, the `SetWindowPos()` function works, and I succesfully moved my the `CPropertySheet` object to the correct location.

However, then I tried to incorporate this `CPropertyPage` into another parent `CPropertySheet`. This is when the `SetWindowPos()` function doesn't work.

It seems like it ignores it when I have a `CPropertySheet` on a  `CPropertyPage`, which is included in another `CPropertySheet`. Does anybody have any idea why?

EDITED: Added extra code and pictures.

The code:

Pane 'pane.h':

```
CPropertySheet SheetSettings;
```

Top `CPropertySheet`, top.h:

```
CMyDlg         PageMyDlg;

Onsize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
```

Top `CPropertySheet`, top.cpp:

```
Top::Top()
{
    SheetSettings.AddPage(&PageMyDlg);
}

Top::Onsize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
     if(SheetSettings.GetSafeHwnd())
     {
          SheetSettings.MoveWindow(0, 0, cx, cy);
          CRect Rect;
          SheetSettings.GetClientRect(Rect);
          Rect.InflateRect(-2, -4, -2, -2);
          SheetSettings.GetTabControl()->MoveWindow(Rect.left, Rect.top, Rect.Width(), Rect.Height());
          SheetSettings.GetTabControl()->AdjustRect(FALSE, Rect);
          if (Page12nc.GetSafeHwnd())
              Page12nc.MoveWindow(Rect.left, Rect.top, Rect.Width(), Rect.Height());

      }
       // CPane holds the page where the CPropertySheet is drawn.
       CPane::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
}
```

Dialog 'CMyDlg', MyDlg.h:

```
CPropertySheet _dlgPropSheet;
```

Dialog 'CMyDlg', MyDlg.cpp:

```
CRect rcSheet;
_dlgPropSheet.GetParent()->GetWindowRect(&rcSheet);
ScreenToClient( &rcSheet );
// This goes wrong.
_dlgPropSheet.SetWindowPos( NULL, rcSheet.left+26, rcSheet.top+223, rcSheet.Width(), rcSheet.Height(), SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE );
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyRT4.png) is what I get when I `.doModal()` my `CMyDlg`.

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAG34.png) is what it draws when bottom is drawn on top.

Comment: [mcve] required.

Comment: You probably should add a picture that shows what you want.

Comment: @IInspectable done.

Comment: @Jabberwocky done.

Comment: Why not just set your sheet/page up to use dynamic resizing?

Comment: I can't figure out what type control you have. It looks like a child window, not property sheet. Use tabs to insert tab control inside a window or dialog.

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/143/Q143291/

> The CPropertySheet remembers the size and position of its
> CPropertyPages when they are first created. When a different tab is
> selected by the user, the CPropertySheet receives a TCN_SELCHANGE
> notification. In response to this, the CPropertySheet shows the new
> page using the size and position it had when it was first created.

So basically, you can change it all you want, but CPropertySheet is just going to change it right back.  The page I linked gives a suggestion to use the OnSize() method.